# Reliability of Google Maps Geocode Data

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

We use the Google Maps API for Business as the basis for a product that we sell and maintain.

Among other things, we rely on the various address tag results in the response from the Geocoder API to help classify the response and perform certain actions.

In particular, we take a geocode response and then take the Locality text to perform certain further actions.

We have been using the `<short_name>` tag as at the time we first built the application the `<Long_Name>` tag was unnecessarily verbose in many cases (e.g. 'City of London' rather than 'London' etc).

Recently it seems there has been an update to the Google data such that many addresses in Germany and Spain are returning single or double letter short_names (e.g. Munich short_name = "M") which has played havoc with our application.

I tried to trace down if there was a mechanism for being informed of these changes but the answer was a firm 'no. Just check them regularly and see if they change'

**So my question is**: Has anyone else that relies on any of the address tags in the google maps api  been similarly affected and have you come up with a good way (programatically or otherwise) to protect yourself from these kinds of un-announced changes?

I'm considering writing some kind of polling mechanism to pass a database of addresses to the API on a daily basis and checking for changes, but this seems to be excessive and am interested in other ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how your application is set up, but I ran across a similar problem recently. I was using an external API that was not always consistent, and I needed to run tests against it. As a solution, I wrote integration tests that used mocks and then wrote a set of integration contract tests (http://martinfowler.com/bliki/IntegrationContractTest.html). They would periodically be run and verify that the API I was using was both working, and matched my test mocks. May not be exactly what you are looking for, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Nice idea and good suggestion in the link. I'll take it into account. Thanks!